# How to get filename's prefix ID # into List array with RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex

How to get filename's prefix ID # into List array with RegEx?  Or alternative method if you know of better one.

I only wants the 111, 222, and 333 values  (ID #).

```
var myList = new List<string>();

myList.Add("foo/0000-0000-0001/111_Age_3_20150518T0800-0400.txt");
myList.Add("foo/0000-0000-0002/222_Bal_3_20120518T0800-0400.txt");
myList.Add("foo/0000-0000-0003/333_DDS_3_20140518T0800-0400.txt");

var filteredFiles2.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, @"^[^\d]+").Value).Distinct();
```

Comment: Check http://www.regexlib.com, they have a large library of pre-made regex's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Path` class to get the filename and then split it:

```
var filteredFiles = myList.Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).Split('_').First()).ToList();
```

Comment: Oh wow!  You made this looks so easy.  Everyone been telling me to use RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the Regex function (i.e. class requirement)?

If not, you could just brute force it, like below:

```
    private List<String> myList;

    private void Init()
    {
        myList = new List<string>();

        myList.Add("foo/0000-0000-0001/111_Age_3_20150518T0800-0400.txt");
        myList.Add("foo/0000-0000-0002/222_Bal_3_20120518T0800-0400.txt");
        myList.Add("foo/0000-0000-0003/333_DDS_3_20140518T0800-0400.txt");
    }

    private string[] filtered()
    {
        var list = new List<String>();
        foreach (var line in myList)
        {
            var split1 = line.Split('/');
            if (split1.Length == 3)
            {
                var split2 = split1[2].Split('_');
                if (split2.Length == 4)
                {
                    list.Add(split2[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: People been telling me to use RegEx.

Comment: @fletchsod - Are these actual file paths? If so, there are built in File functions you could use.

Comment: yea, file paths.  I read them into list array then use list array for building error reports.

Comment: @Raidri's answer from 54 seconds ago shows how to use the `System.IO.Path` - which was what I was going to suggest for files.